# Angular JS Express JS Node JS file upload issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Please help me 
I'm new to this and for file upload I referred to this - http://goodheads.io/2015/06/22/handling-file-uploads-using-angularjs-node-and-express/

my implementation is given below. At place I have deleted things to make sure the post size is readable enough. The main problem is only file upload section other than that everything is working like a charm. Please help.

Here is the index.html section.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<table width="500" border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <form>
  <tbody>
 <tr>
      <td><input type="file" ng-file-select="fileSelected($files)" accept="'image/*'"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" ng-click="uploadFile()" ></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</form>
</table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../bower_components/ng-file-upload-shim/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/ng-file-upload-shim/ng-file-upload.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
<form></form>
```

Here is the controller that is guiding the file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'upload', function($scope, $http, $upload) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");

    $scope.addData = function() 
    {
        console.log($scope.user);
        console.log("whore");
        $http.post('../addData', $scope.user).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
     });

     $scope.fileSelected = function(files) 

     {
        if (files && files.length) {
            $scope.file = files[0];
        }

     $upload.upload({
       url: '../upload',
       file: $scope.file
     })
     .success(function(data) {
       console.log(data, 'uploaded');
      });   


     };
};

}]);
```

Please ignore the first function it is for something else but my problem is something else.

Now here is the server code where I have used multer to do the trick.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var multer = require('multer');
var validator = require('node-mongoose-validator');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(multer({ 
 dest: './uploads/'
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The server file is very big therefore I'm not adding all the routes and all section here. When I'm deleting the section which has the upload command it runs without error but when I am adding it, error is shown.

```
C:\nodefiles\new\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:209
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');
          ^
TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
    at EventEmitter.use (C:\nodefiles\new\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:209:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodefiles\new\server.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multer({dest: './uploads/'})` does not itself return a middleware function.
You have to use one of the functions of `multer` class to get a middleware function.

So you would end up using it like `multer({...}).single()`. The different functions are described here - https://github.com/expressjs/multer#singlefieldname.

Multer doc has good examples of the right usage: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage

To save a click, here is a full working example:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({
    dest: __dirname + '/../../public/uploads/',
});

app.post('/api/data', upload.single('filenameInTheForm'), function (req, res, next) {
    return res.ok();
});
```

Important to note that `filenameInTheForm` must match the field name in the `multipart/form-data` request.

Also, there is a slight difference in using `app.use(..)` and the way described above. `app.use()` will cause the middleware executed for every endpoint, lucky enough, if the content type is not `multipart/form-data` the middleware does nothing. To avoid slight overhead from the fact that it still performs the content type check, it is nicer to use it as in the example above.

Comment: thanks for your time. Can you please show that example in a better manner. As in, tutorial type, please. I want to save the file and have the url  as well to save it to the database. I'm going to read the github document in the meantime.

Comment: Added a working example. Just change the directory to whatever you want and ``filenameInTheForm`` must match the file input name. You are good to go! I suggest you still read the Multer documentation, it will brighten your day.

Comment: thanks @tiblu I have implemented the code and it is working without any errors. I am having some other problem, please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/32382799/5225363 if you have enough time. There is some problem plus the control is not calling the server section as well.

Comment: Done, can you please check my other thread if you have time. Thanks a ton.